# Copy/Move from one list folder to another

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I found this link [here](http://mylittlesharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/05/move-items-into-folder.html), however, in this situation it doesn't help me.

The reason for this is that I cannot copy attachments to the new item, and also cannot copy comments (that are tracked in a "change log"). Comments and attachments are both required.

I've also tried doing an "update item" type workflow on the item to set the "Folder" value to the value I want the folder to move to, but it doesn't move it (even though the workflow says it processed successfully)

I cannot progra

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually using the 'Site Content and Structure' page in site settings.

**OR ELSE**

When copying & pasting large amounts of data between lists, or between folders in a list, I find it useful to create custom datasheet views in the source & destination lists that only display the columns that you need to copy.  These columns are all editable - i.e. not system generated/read only.  You also need to make sure that the column ordering in both views match.  If your destination list is the same as your source then you only need the one custom datasheet view.  Using this technique you can copy & paste all rows of data from the view at once.

To tell whether a column is read-only, select a cell in the regular datasheet view.  If it is read only, then a read only status will appear in the bottom right corner of the datasheet view.

To copy the data in your scenario you would:

- Create one view containing all the columns that you want to copy, ensuring that none are read only.
- Open two browser windows, one displaying the source folder and one displaying the destination folder.
- View both folders in the newly created custom datasheet view
- Select all the items in the source folder & click copy
- Select the first cell of the first available row in the destination folder and click paste
- All your items should be copied successfully.  Once you have verified that the data has been successfully copied to the destination folder, you can then delete the rows from the source folder.

This works great as long as you don't need to copy any of the system generated content.  If you need to retain the data in the Created By field for example, then the solution would be more involved & could be as simple as creating a custom Author field to paste the Created By data & using List Views/Dataview Web Part to display the content, or could involve writing code.

---

**Using SPD**

Start your copy list item workflow only `Whenever an item is changed`.

Write the first condition as :

```
IF the Status is `approved`
then
Move items
```

So whenever your item is Approved, the copy list item workflow will start and your items will be moved.

For Reference [SharePoint 2007](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/120ea459-2b04-4978-869e-555d8071926e/how-to-copy-list-item-attachment-to-document-library-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows) & [SharePoint 2010](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2514879-53a6-4c13-9485-1257d02e2933/copy-move-list-item-in-sharepoint-designer?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious).

**In case**, this workflow actions/conditions are not working(Bcoz of some version will not work).

Use this conditions:

```
Attached sample workflow and custom activity wsp. Rename attached file from .wsp.txt to .wsp and deploy.

Steps of Deployment -
- Install WSP
- Activate Webapplication Feature for deployment of activities

Usage - 
- In SPD, custom action will be visible on deployment
- Add Custom Action 'Copy List Item between Folders'
- Set item to 'Current Item'
- In Folder To, Type name of Folder, where document is to be copied.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to have it in a workflow. I can't manually move all of the list items.

Comment: Oops!!! Which version of SharePoint you are using? The requirement is on SPD.

Comment: I'm on SP 2013, but can only use SP 2010 workflows because of how the environment is set up. Unfortunately, like I said in the question, the "copy" workaround doesn't work, because I can't copy comments, and I can't copy attachments to the original list items.